# Will a soak in mouthwash hurt mouthpieces?

Tags: maintenance, brass, woodwinds, instrument-cleaning, mouthpieces

I’m teaching wind instruments to grade 7 and 8’s after a decade of teaching primary music. Since covid, my school board mandates a specific cleaning solution must be used for sanitation. Brass and woodwind mouthpieces must sit in Vert2Go for 5-10 minutes minimum. The issue I’m having is even after I rinse them well in clean water, wipe them down and dry them - an unpleasant chemical odour remains. My students are understandably upset with this. I can’t forgo any steps in the sanitation process but is there any reason I couldn’t soak the cork-free pieces in mouthwash? Possibly a watered down mouthwash solution just to cover up the odour? TIA!

Comment: I’m surprised Sterisol is not an acceptable alternative. It’s pretty standard on the east coast of the US.

Comment: What about plain old alcohol?  Most mouthwash is alcohol based, and we don't really need the rest of it to disinfect a surface.

Comment: See if you can get approval for an iodophor type sanitizer.  They are widely used in food service on materials that can't tolerate high temperatures, or where high temperature water is unavailable. (I used one when I used to brew beer).  When iodophor sanitizers dry out there's no odor.  No rinsing is required.

Comment: Apparently hydrogen peroxide can make silver plated items (e.g. brass instrument mouthpieces) go black, which will make them look dirty, even if they're sterile.

Answer (score 0):

It seems highly unlikely that a mouthpiece that survives Vert2Go (which seems to be basically hydrogen peroxide) would be harmed by a mouthwash.